# Firefox and IE - Firefox handling of <span> inside tables (html and css)

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

I am having difficulties getting a span tag to work properly inside a table. It appears as if the entire span tag is being ignored that is defined anywhere in between table tags in Firefox, but in IE this shows up correctly.

Maybe I am missing something, but I have created a small example CSS and html file that displays differently in Firefox and IE. Hopefully someone can tell me why it is behaving this way or how I can rearrange the html to resolve the issue in Firefox.

---main.css---

```
.class1 A:link {color:#960033; text-decoration: none}
.class1 A:visited {color:#960033; text-decoration: none}
.class1 A:hover {color:#0000FF; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none}
.class1 A:active {color:#0000FF; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none}

.class2 A:link {color:#960033; text-decoration: none}
.class2 A:visited {color:#960033; text-decoration: none}
.class2 A:hover {color:#0000FF; text-decoration: none}
.class2 A:active {color:#0000FF; text-decoration: none}
```

---test.htm---

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>Title Page</title>
<style type="text/css">@import url("/css/main.css");</style>
</HEAD>

<span class="class1">
<BODY>

<table><tr><td>
---Insert Hyperlink---<br>
</td></tr>

</span><span class="class2">

<tr><td>
---Insert Hyperlink---<br>

</td></tr></table>

</span>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Gawd, such a mess ... it would be hard to write markup this bad. I especially recoil at the <span> that starts before the <body> (!) and ends before the </body>!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a span there is the short answer, only a `<tr>`

`<body>` should contain your elements, nothing but `<html>` should contain `<body>`

What you are probably after is this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title Page</title>
  <style type="text/css">@import url("/css/main.css");</style>
</head>
<body>
  <span class="class1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>---Insert Hyperlink---<br></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </span>
  <span class="class2">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>---Insert Hyperlink---<br></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Another thing to keep in mind, there's no reason for those spans (table can have a class) or those tables (if you're only using a single cell, use a `<div>` or something), a simple `<div>` would probably do everything you want:

```
<div class="class2">
   ---Insert Hyperlink---
</div>
```

Comment: What Nick said. Technically, IE should ignore it there too. Wrap it in a `<tr><td></td></tr>`, you can always us the td's colspan attribute if you have to.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sorry to say, but your HTML is a mess. The reason that IE will display the span is probably a remnant of the browser wars, when Netscape and Microsoft constantly battled each other of who could make sense of the worst HTML. The only tags allowed inside the `<table>`-tag are `<legend>`, `<colgroup>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`, `<thead>` and `<tr>`. If you want your `<span>` to be visible, place it in `<td>` inside `<tr>`

Something like:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>Title Page</title>
<style type="text/css">@import url("/css/main.css");</style>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
     ---Insert Hyperlink---<br>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="class2"></span>
       ---Insert Hyperlink---<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Also, decide if you are going to use lower or upper case characters in your tags. It makes it easier to follow your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) directly contained by [`table`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element). Basically, text in tables *must* be contained within cells (`td` or `th`), which in turn must be contained by rows (`tr`), which in turn should be contained by `tbody`, `thead`, or `tfoot` elements, which then can be contained by `table`. As of HTML5, `tbody` can formally be implied (whereas previously that was just something browsers did, despite a previous spec requiring something between `table` and `tr`).

The [HTML validation service](http://validator.w3.org) is useful for dealing with these sorts of things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there should be a problem having a SPAN inside a table **assuming it is inside a cell**
Make sure the table itself is formatted correctly with proper rows and cells. IE might be rendering the table even if it is broken

Answer (score 0):

Cant you put the class directly on the tr-tag like this:

```
<table><tr class="class1" ><td>
---Insert Hyperlink---<br>
</td></tr>
```

be aware that your code is nestled, so try keep the classes direct on tags

Answer (score 0):

Your nesting of tags is a mess..

you cannot have

```
<tag1>
 <tag2>
</tag1>
 </tag2>
```

it has to be

```
<tag1>
 <tag2>
 </tag2>
</tag1>
```

and you are also using `span` between `tr` which is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

That's just not valid HTML. you can't just have random tags open and close... try something more like this:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>Title Page</title>
<style type="text/css">@import url("/css/main.css");</style>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<table><tr><td>
<span class="class1">
---Insert Hyperlink---<br>
</span>
</td></tr>


<tr><td>
<span class="class2">
---Insert Hyperlink---<br>
</span>
</td></tr></table>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here: you start the first span outside the body while spans can only be inside the body. Also you can't end/start spans between table and tr tags.

You should use tbody tags to separate the sections of the table:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <title>Title Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">@import url("/css/main.css");</style>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

    <table>

        <tbody class="class1">

            <tr><td>
            ---Insert Hyperlink---<br>
            </td></tr>

        </tbody>
        <tbody class="class2">

            <tr><td>
            ---Insert Hyperlink---<br>

            </td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


    </BODY>
</HTML>
```